# How to display element of list of string in many text field in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, textfield

i have a class that return a widget that create a text field i want call this class in a for loop in other class and every times that call this class text field set different value for my text fields and show text fields in list view how done it and next question about text field is when i set a value to text field and go to next page and back to my page value of text field cleaned and dont show how access to value of it this is my class that create a text field object

```
import 'package:art_man/components/Utility/Keys.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class InputText extends StatefulWidget {

  String _hint, id;
  double height;
  TextEditingController ctrl;
  Color brdercolor;
  double brderwidth;
  double radius;
  double margintop;
  TextAlign textAlign;
  int maxlines;
  Color hintconlor;
  double hintsize;
  double maxlenght;
  TextInputType keyboardtype;
  FontWeight fontWeight;
  TextEditingController controller;

  InputText(this._hint, this.id,
    {this.height,
    this.brdercolor,
    this.brderwidth,
    this.margintop,
    this.radius,
    this.textAlign,
    this.maxlines,
    this.hintconlor,
    this.hintsize,
    this.maxlenght,
    this.keyboardtype,
    this.fontWeight,
    this.controller});

  @override
  myInputText createState() {
    myInputText it = new myInputText(id,_hint,
      height: height,
      brdercolor: brdercolor,
      brderwidth: brderwidth,
      margintop: margintop,
      radius: radius,
      maxlines: maxlines,
      hintconlor: hintconlor,
      alignment: textAlign,
      hintsize: hintsize,
      maxlenght: maxlenght,
      keyboardtype: keyboardtype,
      fontwidth : fontWeight,
      controller: controller);
    return it;
  }
}

class myInputText extends State<InputText> {
  String _hint;
  String id;
  double height;
  Color brdercolor;
  double brderwidth;
  double radius;
  double margintop;
  TextAlign alignment;
  int maxlines;
  Color hintconlor;
  double hintsize;
  double maxlenght;
  TextInputType keyboardtype;
  FontWeight fontwidth;
  TextEditingController  controller ;


  myInputText(this.id,this._hint,
    {this.height,
    this.brdercolor,
    this.brderwidth,
    this.margintop,
    this.radius,
    this.alignment,
    this.maxlines,
    this.hintsize,
    this.hintconlor,
    this.maxlenght,
    this.keyboardtype,
    this.fontwidth,
    this.controller});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: margintop == null ? 1.0 : margintop,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
      height: height == null ? 40.0 : height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: brdercolor == null ? Colors.white : brdercolor,
          width: brderwidth == null ? 0.0 : brderwidth),
      color:  brdercolor == null ? Colors.white : brdercolor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius == null ? 25 : radius)),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        keyboardType: keyboardtype==null?TextInputType.text:keyboardtype,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        inputFormatters: [
          new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(maxlenght==null? 
          30:maxlenght.toInt()),
       ],
     onChanged: (value){
       Kelid.setter(id, value);
       print(Kelid.getter(id));
    },
    textAlign: alignment == null ? TextAlign.right : alignment,
    maxLines: maxlines==null?1:maxlines,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: hintsize==null?14:hintsize,
    ),
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        hintText: _hint,
        errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: fontwidth==null?FontWeight.normal:fontwidth,
            color: hintconlor == null ? Colors.grey : hintconlor,
            fontSize: hintsize == null ? 13 : hintsize)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're looking into generating TextField dynamically and be able to store its values. What you can do here is store TextField values using state management available in Flutter. In this approach, I've used the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to store the TextField values and are saved on every text change. With the TextField values stored, we can easily restore the values on the TextFields.

Complete sample

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => TextFieldDetailsModel(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return _inputText('Hint for index $index', index);
            }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Print all TextField String stored in Provider
          // List<String> listText =
          //     Provider.of<TextFieldDetailsModel>(context, listen: false)
          //         ._textFieldContent;
          // for (int x = 0; x < listText.length; x++) {
          //   debugPrint('Text: ${listText[x]}, index: $x');
          // }

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _inputText(String hint, int index) {
    var _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Consumer<TextFieldDetailsModel>(builder: (BuildContext context,
          TextFieldDetailsModel txtModel, Widget? child) {
        // If Provider List contains value, prefill the TextField
        if (txtModel._textFieldContent.length > 0 &&
            txtModel._textFieldContent.length > index &&
            txtModel._textFieldContent[index].trim() != '') {
          _textEditingController.text = txtModel._textFieldContent[index];
          // set TextField cursor at the end
          _textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _textEditingController.text.length);
        }
        return TextField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          onChanged: (String str) {
            // Only add String if TextField has value
            if (str.trim().isEmpty)
              txtModel.remove(index);
            else
              txtModel.add(str, index);
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: hint),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

// https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple
class TextFieldDetailsModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> _textFieldContent = [];

  UnmodifiableListView<String> get text =>
      UnmodifiableListView(_textFieldContent);

  void add(String text, int? index) {
    if (index != null)
      _textFieldContent.fillAndSet(index, text);
    else
      _textFieldContent.add(text);
    // This call tells the widgets that are listening to this model to rebuild.
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void remove(int index) {
    _textFieldContent.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeAll() {
    _textFieldContent.clear();
    // This call tells the widgets that are listening to this model to rebuild.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

// Create filler for skipping ranges
// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504227/2497859
extension ListFiller<T> on List<String> {
  void fillAndSet(int index, String value) {
    if (index >= this.length) {
      this.addAll(List<String>.filled(index - this.length + 1, ''));
    }
    this[index] = value;
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo

[image: demo]

The values can also be stored only on page change. Create a `List<TextEditingController>` to be assigned on the TextFields generated.

```dart
late List<TextEditingController> _listTextEditingController = [];

...

Widget _inputText(String hint, int index) {
  var _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  _listTextEditingController.add(_textEditingController);
  ...
}
```

On page change (i.e. button trigger), extract all the List values and store it in the Provider.

```dart
for (int x = 0; x < _listTextEditingController.length; x++) {
  Provider.of<TextFieldDetailsModel>(context, listen: false).add(_listTextEditingController[x].text, x);
}
```