# insert value at specific index in empty list dart

Tags: arrays, list, dart

I want to add element at specific index in empty list dart like the following

```
List values = List();
values[87] = {'value': 'hello'};
```

When I try to run this code it shows this error

```
Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 87
```

The solution is to set the list length `List values = List(100);` but the problem is I dont know the length because the index is the id, it can be 87 or 1523 .... so I can not set the length.

Another solution is to use `final sparseList = SplayTreeMap<int, dynamic>();`
and insert the element `sparseList[87] = {'value': 'hello'};`

The problem with SplayTreeMap is I cannon do jsonencode or json.encode to this type of list, it shows this error msg

```
Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'SplayTreeMap<int, dynamic>'
```

Questions:

1- How to set element at a specific index in empty list in dart?

2- How to json encode  a SplayTreeMap  list to send it to the server to php file.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a List in this case? I don't know your full code but a Map<int, dynamic> should fit better this context and then you can encode the map in a way like : `json.encode(myMap.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key.toString(),value)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to add element at specific index in empty list dart like the following

One way would be to add a convenience function to append dummy elements to the `List` if necessary.

```dart
extension ListFiller<T> on List<T> {
  void fillAndSet(int index, T value) {
    if (index >= this.length) {
      this.addAll(List<T>.filled(index - this.length + 1, null));
    }
    this[index] = value;
  }
}

void main() {
  var list = <String>[];
  list.fillAndSet(3, 'world');
  list.fillAndSet(2, 'hello');
  print(list); // Prints: [null, null, hello, world]
}
```

> The problem with SplayTreeMap is I cannon do jsonencode or json.encode to this type of list

The [`jsonEncode` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) states (with emphasis added):

> If value contains objects that are not directly encodable to a JSON string (a value that is not a number, boolean, string, null, list or **a map with string keys**), ...

So the reason why `jsonEncode` failed for `SplayTreeMap<int, dynamic>` is not because it's a `SplayTreeMap` instead of a `Map`/`LinkedHashMap` but because your keys are not `String`s. (`jsonEncode` on a `SplayTreeMap<String, dynamic>` should work.) You could convert your `SplayTreeMap<int, dynamic>` when encoding:

```dart
final sparseList = SplayTreeMap<int, dynamic>();

...

var encoded = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
  for (var mapEntry in sparseList.entries)
    mapEntry.key.toString(): mapEntry.value,
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution with SplayTreeMap worked well, Great.